# ヘルプ センター > 権限 > 反対投票する の誤記

Tags: バグ, 完了

> 回答に反対投票すると、投票者自信から信用度が 1 点削除されます。

誤：投票者自信から
正：投票者自身から

かと存じます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

指摘ありがとうございます。訂正しました：

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

同時に上記のヘルプ、又はプラス票についてなヘルプでは「賛成票・反対票」を「プラス票・マイナス票」にしました。

間違いがあれば、ご教示ください（メタでもいいし、[チャット](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20999/)でもいいです）。